# C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymous type:

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code in .Net and I get this error:

```
C# Cannot implicitly convert type System.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymous type:..
```

Can someone help me figure it out?

```
IQueryable<Reservations> queryRes;
queryRes = (from p in ctx.Reservations
                           join a in ctx.Employees on p.Id_employee equals a.Id
                           join c in ctx.Clients on p.Id_client equals c.Id
                           orderby p.Id
                           select new
                           {
                               p.Date,
                               p.Hour,
                               c.Name,
                               c.Surname,
                               p.Email,
                               p.Phone,
                               p.Service,
                               name1=a.Nume,
                               surname1=a.Prenume
                           });
 reservationsView.Source = queryRes.ToList();
```

Comment: CollectionViewSource reservationsView; reservationsView = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("reservationsViewSource")));

Comment: You are projecting into an anonymous type, project into a `Reservations` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try create a simple ViewModel with any name... "ReservationsView" with the fields you've create on "select new"...

```
public class ReservationsView
    {

        public System.DateTime Date{ get; set; }       
        public string Hour{ get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string Surname{ get; set; }
        public string Email{ get; set; }
        public string Phone{ get; set; }
        public string Email{ get; set; }
        public string name1{ get; set; }
        public string surname1{ get; set; }

    }
```

And then...

```
IQueryable<ReservationsView> queryRes;
queryRes = (from p in ctx.Reservations
                           join a in ctx.Employees on p.Id_employee equals a.Id
                           join c in ctx.Clients on p.Id_client equals c.Id
                           orderby p.Id
                           select new ReservationsView
                           {
                               p.Date,
                               p.Hour,
                               c.Name,
                               c.Surname,
                               p.Email,
                               p.Phone,
                               p.Service,
                               name1=a.Nume,
                               surname1=a.Prenume
                           });
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `select new { ...` creates a new anonymous type. Select everything from `Reservations` or create a custom class with the desired properties.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned select Reservations instead of creating anonymous object,

```
        IQueryable<Reservations> queryRes;
        queryRes = (from p in ctx.Reservations
                    join a in ctx.Employees on p.Id_employee equals a.Id
                    join c in ctx.Clients on p.Id_client equals c.Id
                    orderby p.Id
                    select p);
        reservationsView.Source = queryRes.ToList();
```

Comment: And then how can I diplay the columns that I need from the others tables?

Comment: Do as Rafael R. recommended.,